# Linked Lists Integrated into a Tree Struct

Tags: c, tree, linked-list

I'm creating a Tree Structure, whereby each node of that tree structure, contains a linked list of data (numbers). Now, in my head, that means, each of those linked links obviously need to have a head associated with them, so that I can access the data within them and loop through, displaying all the numbers for that TreeNode. The problem is, I've hit a brick wall, and really don't know what step to take from where I am at the moment ( see below ). I need to return a head for each linked list, for each, TreeNode, I'm unsure how.

Below is my code that I have so far for this, at this moment, it adds the Name to the Node, and a number to the list, but adding multiple numbers to the list, I'm unsure what step to next take, and then how to return an item to allow my ( in time ) print function to loop through.

```
typedef struct ListNode {
char            *number;
struct ListNode *next;
}ListNode;

typedef struct TreeNode {
char            *name;
ListNode        *numbers;
struct TreeNode *left;
struct TreeNode *right;
}TreeNode;

TreeNode* AddNode(TreeNode *, char *, char *);
TreeNode* SearchTree(TreeNode *root, char *search);
void N_Print(TreeNode *root);

int main(void) {
char my_string[50], name[25], number[25];
TreeNode *root = NULL;
while ((fgets(my_string, 50, stdin)) != NULL) {
    if (my_string[0] == '.')
        break;      
sscanf(my_string, "%s %s", name, number); 
root = AddNode(root, name, number);  
}   
return 0;
}

TreeNode* AddNode(TreeNode *root, char *name, char *number) {
int comparison;
if ( root == NULL) {
    root = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    root->numbers = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    root->name = strdup(name); root->numbers->number = strdup(number);
    root->left = root->right = NULL;
    root->numbers->next = NULL;
}else if (( comparison = strcmp(name, root->name)) < 0 )
    root->left = AddNode(root->left, name, number);
else if (comparison > 0) {
    root->right = AddNode(root->right, name, number);
} else if (comparison == 0 ) {
    root->numbers->number = strdup(number);
    root->numbers->next = NULL;
}
return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I've understood your problem correctly...

I would suggest that you add another level of indirection to the list...you could create a List struct that held the head, tail, etc. of the List, and add a List (or pointer to one) instead of ListNode* to the TreeNode struct.  That way you could have a `List* getList(TreeNode*)` and have functions that operate directly on the list returned (this is cleaner in my opinion).  This would mean your list implementation would be completely separate from your tree, meaning you could easily use it outside of this project.

The alternative is to encapsulate the List entirely in the TreeNode struct, which is what I think you're trying to do.  To add to the list, you probably need a function `addNumber(TreeNode*, char*)` and other list manipulation functions would be done similarly.  They just need a reference or pointer to the TreeNode that provides access to the list.

To do what you're trying to do, you already have access to the `ListNode*` if you have a `TreeNode*`:

```
TreeNode* tn = something; 
for(ListNode* ln = tn->numbers; ln != NULL; ln = ln->next) {
    // do something here (print, etc.) with ln->number
}
```

You could easily pop this into a function taking a `TreeNode*` as a parameter.  Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: Nope, I can only use C. Sorry, but is there no way I cant do it working off from my current code, I like to try to stick to my first ideas for the solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to say that with the `addNumber(TreeNode*,int)` part...let me know what is unclear.  Pretty much add all the functions that would work on lists to work on `TreeNode`s instead, which is effectively your list.  It looks like you're using a singly-linked list with a null sentry, right?

Comment: Yeah, I will be using a singly linked list, but nope, Ive been working on this for a while now, still no progress, I just cant see where to start

Comment: @user1048116 I still think it's way better for the `TreeNode` to hold a struct type with all the name, number, and list.  That would simplify things drastically.  But see if my edit helps you.

Answer (score 0):

i make a basic print function to print tree nodes. i also modified functions prototype to make life easier :)

i hope this will help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



typedef struct ListNode ListNode;
typedef struct TreeNode TreeNode;


struct ListNode {
    char            *number;
    ListNode        *next;
};

struct TreeNode {
    char            *name;
    ListNode        *numbers;
    TreeNode        *left;
    TreeNode        *right;
};

TreeNode    *new_tree_node(char *name);
ListNode    *new_list_node(char *number);

void ListNode_AddNode(ListNode **plist, char *number);
void TreeNode_AddNode(TreeNode **proot, char *name, char *number);

void ListNode_Print(ListNode *list);
void TreeNode_Print(TreeNode *root);
TreeNode * TreeNode_FindNode(TreeNode * root,char *name);

/*________________________________________________________________________________________________
*/
int main(void) {
    char my_string[50], name[25], number[25];
    TreeNode *root = NULL;
    while ((fgets(my_string, 50, stdin)) != NULL) {
        if (my_string[0] == '.')
            break;      
        sscanf(my_string, "%s %s", name, number); 
        TreeNode_AddNode(&root, name, number);  
    }

    printf("PRINTING TREENODE:\n");
    TreeNode_Print(root);
    printf("========================================================================= DONE\n\n");

    printf("PRINTING (jaguar's numbers) :\n");

    TreeNode *jaguar = TreeNode_FindNode(root,"jaguar");
    if(jaguar)
        ListNode_Print(jaguar->numbers);
    else
        printf("jaguar node not found");

    printf("\n========================================================================= DONE\n\n");
    return 0;
}
/*________________________________________________________________________________________________
*/
TreeNode *new_tree_node(char *name){
    TreeNode *tree = calloc(1,sizeof(TreeNode));

    if ( tree ) {
        tree->name=strdup(name);
    }
    return tree;
}

ListNode * new_list_node(char *number){
    ListNode *list = calloc(1,sizeof(ListNode));
    if ( list ) {
        list->number=strdup(number);
    }
    return list;
}

void ListNode_AddNode(ListNode **plist, char *number){
    ListNode *list = *plist;
    if( !list ) {
        list = new_list_node (number);
        *plist = list;
    }
    else{
        ListNode_AddNode(&list->next,number);
    }
    return ;
}

void TreeNode_AddNode(TreeNode **proot, char *name, char *number) {

    TreeNode *root = *proot;

    if ( !root ) {
        root    = new_tree_node(name);
        *proot  = root;
    }else {
        int comparison = strcmp(name, root->name);

        if (comparison < 0 ){
            TreeNode_AddNode(&root->left, name, number);
            return;
        }
        if (comparison > 0) {
            TreeNode_AddNode(&root->right, name, number);
            return;
        }
    }

    ListNode_AddNode ( &root->numbers,number);
    return ;
}

void ListNode_Print(ListNode *list){
    if(!list) return;
    printf("%s ",list->number);
    ListNode_Print (list->next);
}

void print_tatbs(int n){
    while( n ){
        n--;
        putchar('\t');
    }
}
void TreeNode_Print(TreeNode *root){
    static int tree_deep = 0;
    if( !root ) 
        return;
    print_tatbs(tree_deep);
    printf("Node: %s, Numbers: ",root->name);
    ListNode_Print(root->numbers);
    printf("\n");


    if(root->left){
        tree_deep++;
        print_tatbs(tree_deep);
        printf("Left:\n");
        TreeNode_Print(root->left);
        tree_deep--;
    }
     if(root->right){
        tree_deep++;
        print_tatbs(tree_deep);
        printf("Right:\n");
        TreeNode_Print(root->right);
        tree_deep--;
    }
}


TreeNode * TreeNode_FindNode(TreeNode * root,char *name){

    if(!root) return root;

    int comparison = strcmp(name, root->name);

    if (comparison < 0 )
        return TreeNode_FindNode(root->left, name);

    if (comparison > 0)
        return TreeNode_FindNode(root->right, name);

   return root; 
}
```